# Adjacency matrix from DiGraph in networkx

Tags: graph, networkx

It seems that currently I can extract the adjacency list of a directed graph at networkx, however it is not supported to directed extract the adjacency matrix. How can I extract the adjacency matrix from a DiGraph in networkx?

Answer (score 2):

[`nx.adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) returns a SciPy sparse (adjacency) matrix. To get a dense (NumPy) matrix, call it's [`todense`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.todense.html) method:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(4, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
m = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
print(m)
#   (0, 1)  1
#   (1, 2)  1
#   (2, 3)  1

print(m.todense())
# [[0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0]
#  [0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0]]
```

Alternatively, call [`nx.to_numpy_matrix`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix.html):

```
print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(G))
# [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

To get a pure Python list of lists, call the NumPy matrix's [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method:

```
print(m.todense().tolist())
# [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```